# 404 error for login page in spring boot security... I am working in intellj idea community version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring boot security.And it is not able to find login page

This is my folder structure.

```
resources
  static
      home.html
      login.html
  templates
      index.html
```

This is security Config file

```
enter code here
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception{
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("dan")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .withUser("joe")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
 }

}
```

this is my webconfig file

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    super.addViewControllers(registry);
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home.html");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.html");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
  }
 }
```

Please help. How to solve this error

Comment: the view name is `login` not `login.html`. The same applies to `home.html` and they should be in the `template` directory (assuming you are using thymleaf). If you want them to be static then provide the correct `loginPage`. Something like `/static/login.html` in your security configuration (as you aren't then resolving to a view).

Comment: Is there any reason why `login` and `home` html files are placed in `static` folder? Ideally all html/jsp/view templates should be in `templates` folder and `css/js` and static content has to be in `static` folder. Can you copy/move `login` and `home` html files to `templates` folder, refresh your workspace and try?

Comment: It is working fine when I am writing .loginPage("/login.html") in security configuration file.

Comment: harshavmb. yes there is a reason for placing all the files in static folder, because I am using thymleaf and by default it search for html files in static folder. otherwise it will  able to find html files in templates folder

Comment: @saniya if you are using spring boot, by default it will search the .html files in templates folder(assuming you are using thymeleaf template) and remove .html from suffix

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine while specifying html file instead of just writing name of file.
Modifying above code.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .authorizeRequests()

            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/login.html")
               .permitAll()
               .and()
            .logout()
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
               .permitAll();
                http.csrf().disable();
             }
```

Also remove .html from setviewname

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
   super.addViewControllers(registry);
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
 }
 }
```